# TextDecoder is not defined in stripe.webhooks.constructEvent

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to test a stripe endpoint

```
router.post("/webhook", (req, res) => {
  const signature = req.headers["stripe-signature"];
  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, signature, endpointSecret);
    // console.log(req.body);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log({ ERROR: "ERROOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOR", MESSAGE: err.message });
    res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    return;
  }
})
```

But I always get an error that says: `TextDecoder is not defined`.
I'm using Node v10.9 and stripe v^11.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum Node runtime version for stripe-node is v12 : https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#requirements

TextDecoder which the Stripe library is using, was added in node v11 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder#browser_compatibility

To fix this you need to update your Node environment.